# Java thread program stops running with no error message (mac terminal/command prompt)

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

The purpose of this program is to send text messages (strings) between a client and a server (using java threads) like two phones would send text messages to each other.

If "-l" is present in the command line arguments, then it will run the server thread. If "-l" is not present on the command line arguments, then it will run the client thread.

In the screenshot below, the left window is the server and the right is the client.

[image]

The problem with the screenshot is that the left window (server) is supposed to output "Message received from client: Hello", and then proceed to output "Standard input (press enter then control D when finished):"

I used "ok1, ok2, ok3, ok4" as standard output for debugging purposes (you will notice what lines it stops at in the code)" so it can be deleted in the future.

There are three files: The main function file, the server file, the client file.

Code of Server (DirectMessengerServer.java):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
//import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class DirectMessengerServer
{
    private static Socket socket;
    boolean KeepRunning = true;
    void ServerRun(String[] args)
    {
        Thread Server = new Thread () 
        {
            public void run ()
            {   
                System.out.println("Server thread is now running");
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                    int port_number1= Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
                    System.out.println("Port number is: " + port_number1);
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
                    //SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(address, port_number1);
                    System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                    System.out.println( "Listening on port: " + ( port_number1 ) );

                    while(KeepRunning)
                    {
                        System.out.println("While loop run");
                        //Reading the message from the client

                        socket = serverSocket.accept();    
                        System.out.println("ok1");
                        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                        System.out.println("ok2");
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                        System.out.println("ok3");
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        System.out.println("ok4");
                        String MessageFromClient = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println("ok5");
                        System.out.println("Message received from client: "+ MessageFromClient);


                        //creating message to server send from standard input
                        String newmessage = "";
                        try {
                            // input the message from standard input
                            BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader( 
                              new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                            String line = "";

                            System.out.println( "Standard input (press enter then control D when finished): " );

                            while( (line= input.readLine()) != null && KeepRunning==true )      
                            {
                                newmessage += line + " \n ";
                            }
                            }
                        catch ( Exception e ) {
                            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                        }




                        //Writing return message back to client
                        String returnMessage = newmessage;
                        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                        bw.write(returnMessage);
                        System.out.println("Message sent to client: "+returnMessage);
                        bw.flush();
                        //shutdown with zero-length message
                        if(MessageFromClient.equals("") || MessageFromClient.equals(null) || returnMessage.equals(""))
                        {
                            KeepRunning=false;
                            System.out.println("Shutting down");
                            System.exit(0);
                            socket.close();
                            serverSocket.close();
                        }



                    }
                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }  
                finally
                {
                    //Closing the socket
                    try
                    {
                        socket.close();


                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        };
        Server.start();
    }
}
```

Code of Client (DirectMessengerClient.java):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class DirectMessengerClient
{
    boolean KeepRunning = true;
    private static Socket socket;
    //static String[] arguments;
    //public static void main(String[] args)
    //{
    //  arguments = args;
    //}
    public DirectMessengerClient()
    {

        //System.out.println("test.");

    }
    public void ClientRun(String[] args)
    {
        Thread Client = new Thread ()
        {
          public void run()
          {   
                System.out.println("Client thread is now running");

                    try
                    {
                            System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                            String port_number1= args[0];
                            System.out.println("Port number is: " + port_number1);
                            int port = Integer.valueOf(port_number1);
                            System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                            System.out.println( "Listening on port: " + port_number1 );

                            while(KeepRunning)
                            {
                                String host = "localhost";
                                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                                socket = new Socket(address, port);


                                //Send the message to the server
                                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                                //creating message to send from standard input
                                String newmessage = "";
                                try 
                                {
                                    // input the message from standard input
                                    BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader( 
                                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                                    String line = "";

                                    System.out.println( "Standard input (press enter then control D when finished): " );

                                    while( (line= input.readLine()) != null )       
                                    {
                                        newmessage += line + " ";
                                    }
                                }
                                catch ( Exception e )
                                {
                                    System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                                }
                                String sendMessage = newmessage;
                                bw.flush();
                                System.out.println("Message sent to server: "+sendMessage);

                                //Get the return message from the server
                                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                                String messageFromServer = br.readLine();
                                System.out.println("Message received from server: " + messageFromServer);

                            }
                }

                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally
                {
                    //Closing the socket
                    try
                    {
                        socket.close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

          }
        };

    Client.start(); 
    }
}
```

Code of main (DirectMessengerCombined.java):

```
public class DirectMessengerCombined
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DirectMessengerClient Client1 = new DirectMessengerClient();
        DirectMessengerServer Server1 = new DirectMessengerServer();
          for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
          {
                if(!args[0].equals("-l"))
                {
                    Client1.ClientRun(args);
                }
                switch (args[0].charAt(0))
                {
                    case '-':
                    if(args[0].equals("-l"))
                    {   
                        Server1.ServerRun(args);
                    }

                }
           i=args.length + 20;
          } 
    }

}
```

My questions is: Why does the program stop running at the line where ok4 is outputted (server window)? There's no error message so I am also wondering how to find the error message if I'm missing it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DirectMessengerClient` class, you are never sending the message to the server. Add a line to your code to do that:

```
String sendMessage = newmessage;
bw.write(sendMessage + "\n"); // <--- ADD THIS LINE
bw.flush();
System.out.println("Message sent to server: "+sendMessage);
```

Also note, in the server class, you are sending a return message. But the call to `BufferedWriter.write` does not add a newline to the end of the message (unlike `System.out.println`), so you need to add that yourself if you want to be able to read the line using `BufferedReader.readLine`:

```
bw.write(returnMessage + "\n");
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.